# Why won't my anchor tags work in mobile view?

Tags: html, debugging, html-email

I'm writing email code not sure why my `<a/>` link won't work in mobile view when in portrait mode.  In landscape view and desktop view, it works fine.  I've looked up countless SO posts and other miscellaneous material regarding this issue but to no avail.

I tried adding `z-index: -1;` on my `<img/>` tag but that didn't do anything (this was the latest thing I tried).  What am I doing wrong?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
     .width-320 {
        width: 320px !important;
     }

     .overload {
        display: block !important;
     }

}


<tr>
<td class="width-320" width="600">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="overload width-320" width="240">
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="width-320" width="600"><a href="www.google.com"> <img class="hide" style="display: block;" src="myImage" alt="The Image" width="600" height="295" border="0" /> </a></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

Comment: When I mimic mobile it seems to work fine for me, - are you just viewing this html file locally?

Comment: @Jonny Yeah I'm viewing this file locally and I've also tried sending myself a test email and it won't work there either.  I'm dealing with a large codebase so I can't really post it all because it'll be too much :).

Comment: If i simply copy and paste the code you've provided it works fine for me.
The only thing that happens is that the actual link doesn't load (because you haven't specified http/https on the url) but doing that makes it work fine, is this what you are referring to?

Comment: @Jonny oh yeah, I have https in the real link I'm using.  I'm just trying to make it click through on mobile view on landscape... this is so strange :(.

Comment: And this issue is happening even say if you're viewing mobile version through chrome dev tools on desktop? If so can you post all your code?

Comment: @Jonny It's really wayyy too much for me to post.  But what I can say it that in my chrome dev tools, the `<a/>` has dimension of `0x0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201387/discussion-between-testman-and-jonny).

Comment: Maybe it's something silly like that space between 320px and !important?